# Angular Directive - ElementRef - Cannot select mat-select from mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material, directive

I'm trying, via a directive, to access a `mat-select` inside of a `mat-form-field`.

```js
@Directive({ selector: "[appMatSelectLoader]" })
export class MatSelectLoaderDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        console.log((el.nativeElement as HTMLElement).querySelector("mat-select"));
    }
}
```

I get `null` in the console. However, when I do this:

```js
console.log((el.nativeElement as HTMLElement));
```

I do see the `mat-select` in the console:
[image]

What am I missing here ??

Here is how the directive is applied:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" appMatSelectLoader>
    <mat-select required>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.id">
            {{ option.name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Can you please explain Why do you want to access mat-select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to query the dom before the view has been initialized

```
export class MatSelectLoaderDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  el: ElementRef;
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
      this.el = el;
    }
    
    ngAfterViewInit () {
        console.log((this.el.nativeElement as HTMLElement).querySelector("mat-select"));
    }
}
```

Comment: ha, make sense :) Thank you